# In the MySQL secondary index, are the primary keys on the leaf nodes ordered?

Tags: mysql

mysql index

In the MySQL secondary index, are the primary keys on the leaf nodes ordered?

Physical structure in MySQL secondary index

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: This sounds like a good question for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Because this problem affects the default sorting method and sorting efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of innodb implicitly add the primary key to all other keys.  E.g. `index (foo)` is actually `index (foo,pk)`.  So different pk values will be in different leaf nodes (if I understand what you mean by that term).

Comment: If so, the primary key is ordered, this is the first time I've heard of it. Does the MySQL official website also have such a description?

Comment: "each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: you can also clearly see this in query plans; see the difference in key_len and ref in https://dbfiddle.uk/XvyEibZ5.  the second explain clearly shows that foo_index is composite.

Comment: "different pk values will be in different leaf nodes"
Another question is: "Will the id value be saved repeatedly in the leaf node data area?"

Comment: yes, it will.  from that same page, "If the primary key is long, the secondary indexes use more space, so it is advantageous to have a short primary key."

Comment: Why doesn't the data area delete the storage of the primary key, because they are duplicated

Comment: I'm not super clear on what you mean by data area.  if you mean does each index entry store the primary key twice, once as a key and once as a value, I doubt it does.  I would guess there are only keys and no values.  But that's just based on what makes sense to me, not anything I know for a fact.